# How do I check how many servers my bot is in

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I have this code

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "servers",
  aliases: [],
  category: "Infos",
  utilisation: "{prefix}servers",

  execute(client, message) {
    message.channel.send(
      `${client.emotes.success} - ${client.user.username} is in **${client.guilds.size}** servers !`,
    );
  },
};
```

The problem is that it is sending `... is in undefined servers !`.

Comment: It's quite impossible to help with just that code. What gives you "undefined servers"?

Comment: It's `client.guilds.cache.size` in v12. Probably better to close this.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `client.guilds.cache.size`, as you're doing it in Discord.js V12.

[Updating from V11 to V12 (cache, discordjs.guide)](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#managers-cache)